# Make listarray accessible over all activities

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have several activities and i want on each activity add some Integer to list 
in other words I want myList are able to add Integers from each activity

but when calling size of myList  it return 0 .

first class :

```
public class BatteryActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyApplication hh = new MyApplication();
    hh.MyApplication1(10);}
```

second class :

```
 public class elseActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyApplication hh = new MyApplication();
    hh.MyApplication1(500);}
```

wrapper class :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void MyApplication1(int hesham) {

    this.myList.add(hesham);

}

public List<Integer> MyApplication2() {

    return this.myList;
}
```

calling Mylist size();

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),    String.valueOf(hh.MyApplication2().size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the public mofifier before declaring the list

```
public List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```